# Text file input using buffer reader, parse it and store in json array format using java and make one PUT api call

Tags: java, json, api, text-files, bufferedreader

I have a text file where i am trying to fetch data one by one and store it in rri section with current time stamp under one PUT call but currently its fetching only one value or multiple request? Kindly help me to get through it. I will be sharing the text file and expected result in the comment section below.

```
        File file = new File("DataToInput.txt");
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        String line;

    String urlString= "http://34.237.64.52 /v1/iot-hitoe-analytics/groups/0d98a4d3-207c-41e3-a943-363b73d58adf/raw-data";
    URL url = new URL(urlString);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", 
            "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)");
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.setRequestMethod("PUT");
   //conn.connect();
    conn.setRequestProperty("content-type", "application/json");        
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

JSONObject Main = new JSONObject();    
JSONArray alldata = new JSONArray();
JSONObject alldata1 = new JSONObject();

JSONObject metadata = new JSONObject();
    metadata.put("sensorTypeId", sensorTypeId);
    metadata.put("sensorId", sensorId);
    metadata.put("sensorName", sensorName);
    metadata.put("connectionMode",connectionMode);

JSONObject owner = new JSONObject();
     owner.put("groupId", groupId);
     owner.put("entityId", entityId);


JSONObject sensordata = new JSONObject();
JSONObject rawRri = new JSONObject();
JSONArray samples_rri = new JSONArray();
JSONObject samples1_rri = new JSONObject();

while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] fields = line.split(" ");

   // System.out.println("fields size is "+fields.length);
   // System.out.println("fields value is "+fields[0]);
    stringBuffer.append(line);
    stringBuffer.append("\n");
}

    samples1_rri.put("rri",line);
    samples1_rri.put("timestamp",System.currentTimeMillis());

samples_rri.put(samples1_rri);
rawRri.put("samples", samples_rri);
sensordata.put("rawRri", rawRri);


alldata1.put("metadata", metadata);
alldata1.put("owner", owner);
alldata1.put("sensordata", sensordata);
alldata.put(alldata1);
Main.put("alldata", alldata);


String payload = Main.toString();

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
Object json = mapper.readValue(payload, Object.class);
String indented = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(json);
System.out.println(indented);

/*OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8");
writer.write(indented);
writer.close();*/

    fileReader.close();
    bufferedReader.close();
    //System.out.println("Contents of file:");
    System.out.println(stringBuffer.toString());

    URLEncoder.encode(urlString,"UTF-8");
        System.out.println("response codec: "+conn.getResponseCode());
      //  if (conn.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_CREATED) {
        if (conn.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_CREATED) {
       // throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
         //           + conn.getResponseCode());
            System.out.println("response received!!");   
        }



        else {
        System.out.println("response: "+conn.getInputStream());
        }

        BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                (conn.getInputStream())));

        String output;
        System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
        while ((output = br1.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(output);
        }
```

Comment: > #Text file content is:#
>742
>709
>691
>715
>731
>734
>758
>775
>769
>754
>765
>764
>732
>742
>747
>743
>728
>743
>745
>730
>736
>751
>758
>739
>726
>706
>692
>686
>689
>691
>689
>685
>705
>731
>727
>739
>745
>734
>717
>716
>708
>693
>675
>677

Comment: #Expected output is:#
    {
  "alldata" : [ {
   "owner" : {
      "groupId" : "XXX",
      "entityId" : "XXX"
    },
    "metadata" : {
      "connectionMode" : "realtime",
      "sensorName" : "sensorTypeId" : "hitoe_D01",
      "sensorId" : "aa-bb-cc1"
    },
    "sensordata" : {
     "rawRri" : {
        "samples" : [ {
          "rri" : "742",
          "timestamp" : 1514521746423
        }, {
          "rri" : "738",
          "timestamp" : 1514521746446
        }, {
          "rri" : "741",
          "timestamp" : 1514521746500
        }
}]
}]
}